# Count the data in the nested list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list. In the list, it has a date and a name. I want the count the users on the date. For example,In '2019-10-11', there are 5 users. But sam user already exists, so i count it as 4. Here's the list

```
a =[['sam', '2019-10-11'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['king', '2019-10-11'],
    ['queen', '2019-10-10'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['kumar', '2019-10-11'],
    ['jeba', '2019-10-11'], ['sam', '2019-10-10'], ['sam', '2019-10-11'],
    ['howl', '2019-10-14']]
```

Output Required:

```
a = [['2019-10-10','2019-10-11','2019-10-12','2019-10-14'],[2,4,1,1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? have you tried iterating over each list, recording the date and adding the unique names to each corresponding date?

Comment: No. I have tried this `res1, res2 = map(list, zip(*a))` which seperated my list. Further i don't where to move on. It has more number of data.

Comment: What happend to `'2019-10-10'`?

Comment: On 2019-10-10 you have a user "sam". Why is he not in the output?

Comment: Yes. it should be counted as 2

Comment: you are looking for `from collections import Counter;list(zip(*Counter(list(zip(*set(zip(*zip(*a)))))[1]).items()))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the code given below it iterates over the array and count keys in a json b

```
a =[['sam', '2019-10-11'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['king', '2019-10-11'],
    ['queen', '2019-10-10'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['kumar', '2019-10-11'],
    ['jeba', '2019-10-11'], ['sam', '2019-10-10'], ['sam', '2019-10-11'],
    ['howl', '2019-10-14']]

b = {}

for iter in a:
  if iter[1] in b:
    if(iter[0] not in b[iter[1]]):
      b[iter[1]][iter[0]] = 1
  else:
    b[iter[1]] = {iter[0]: 1}

    print(b)
```

the result of above code will be:

```
{'2019-10-11': {'sam': 1, 'king': 1, 'kumar': 1, 'jeba': 1}, '2019-10-12': {'ram': 1}, '2019-10-10': {'queen': 1, 'sam': 1}, '2019-10-14': {'howl': 1}}
```

Of course you can convert it into array structure like this

```
for key in b:
  print(key, len(b[key]))
  res[0].append(key)
  res[1].append(len(b[key]))
```

the result would be

```
[['2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-14'], [4, 1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: The `output` seems to be wrong from what the `user` wanted as output :/

Answer (score 2):

You could use `defaultdict` from `collections` like,

```
>>> a =[['sam', '2019-10-11'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['king', '2019-10-11'],
...     ['queen', '2019-10-10'], ['ram', '2019-10-12'], ['kumar', '2019-10-11'],
...     ['jeba', '2019-10-11'], ['sam', '2019-10-10'], ['sam', '2019-10-11'],
...     ['howl', '2019-10-14']]
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set) # using `set` to not care about duplicate `name` on same `date`, otherwise use `list` instead of `set`
>>> # and use `d[date].append(name)`
>>> for name, date in a:
...   d[date].add(name) # maybe, two users can be there for the same date ?
... 
>>> data = [(k,len(v)) for k,v in sorted(d.items())]
>>> data
[('2019-10-10', 2), ('2019-10-11', 4), ('2019-10-12', 1), ('2019-10-14', 1)]
>>> list(zip(*data)) # returns a `list` of `tuple`s which usually should be fine for any iteration
[('2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'), (2, 4, 1, 1)]
>>> required = [list(x) for x in zip(*data)] # if you really want `list` of `list`s
>>> required
[['2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'], [2, 4, 1, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

list(zip(*Counter(list(zip(*set(zip(*zip(*a)))))[1]).items()))

Out[54]: [('2019-10-11', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'), (4, 2, 1, 1)]
```

this can be simplified as:

```
list(zip(*Counter([j for _, j in set([tuple(i) for i in a])]).items()))

[('2019-10-11', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'), (4, 2, 1, 1)]
```

another way to go about this without importing modules:

```
b = set(zip(*zip(*a)))
d = {}

for name,date in b:
    d[date] = d.get(date,0)+1
list(zip(*d.items()))

[('2019-10-11', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'), (4, 2, 1, 1)]
```

if you need sorted list of lists, you could do:

```
[list(i) for i in zip(*sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[0]))]
Out[112]: [['2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'], [2, 4, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the output should be in the form of list of list `[['2019-10-11', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-14'], [4, 2, 1, 1]]` and it should be sorted

Comment: @crustsalty you can simply sort your dictionary ie. `[list(i) for i in zip(*sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[0]))]`